# Creating XML file from document library document properties

Tags: 2007, document-library, metadata, xml

I have many documents in document library with different content types. For each document metadata (document properties) in the library i want to create XML file.

How can i create XML file from each document metadata (document properties) in document library in share point 2007?

Comment: Document Library RSS Feed might be your best bet.

Comment: Use server side code to go through all document properties and create a xml file using xmlwriter